# How do I number all the chapters but the first?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

It seems that `\tableofcontents` gets assigned the number `0` when using the `article` class. I want that remove – basically, remove the `0` and keep everything else the same.

[image]

This is the code:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 
               12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            right    = 25mm,
            left     = 30mm,
            top      = 25mm,
            bottom   = 25mm,
            head     = 12.5mm,
            foot     = 12.5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{CONTENTS}
\setlength{\parindent}{12.5mm}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering \bfseries}{}{14pt}{\thechapter. ~}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{}{14pt}{\thesection.\quad}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{}{14pt}{\thesubsection.\quad}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{roman}
 
\begin{document}

\chapter{FOO}

\section{Foo}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\subsection{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what your needed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
               12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            right    = 25mm,
            left     = 30mm,
            top      = 25mm,
            bottom   = 25mm,
            head     = 12.5mm,
            foot     = 12.5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{CONTENTS}
\setlength{\parindent}{12.5mm}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering \bfseries}{\thechapter.}{14pt}{}% Don't need ~ here
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{}{14pt}{\thesection.\quad}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{}{14pt}{\thesubsection.\quad}

\pagenumbering{roman}
 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{FOO}

\section{Foo}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\subsection{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `\titleformat` declarations are wrong.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper, 
  12pt
]{report}

\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  right    = 25mm,
  left     = 30mm,
  top      = 25mm,
  bottom   = 25mm,
  head     = 12.5mm,
  foot     = 12.5mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{CONTENTS}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\filcenter\bfseries}
  {\thechapter. }
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\bfseries}
  {\thesection.}{1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection.}
  {1em}
  {}

\linespread{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{12.5mm}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{FOO}

\section{Foo}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\subsection{Bar}

\end{document}
```

The third argument to `\titleformat` is for the numbering; it will be omitted, together with the spacing specified in the next argument, for unnumbered sectional units.

If you want indented section titles, then use the corresponding `\titlespacing` declarations.

I also made a few modifications:

1. the `times` package is obsolete; use `newtxtext` and also `newtxmath` if your document has math;
2. I added `heightrounded` to the options for `geometry`, so the text height will be slightly adjusted to ensure an integer number of lines;
3. I changed the redefinition of `\baselinestretch` into the better `\linespread` declaration;
4. in the `\titleformat` declarations, `\filcenter` is to be preferred to `\centering`.

[image]